# Criptografar senha no banco de dados Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, laravel, segurança

Criei uma API para cadastro de usuários no db.
Mas me deparei com o seguinte problema:
Preciso criptografar as senhas no banco de dados.
Poderiam me ajudar como fazer isso? Lendo a documentação fiquei muito perdido.
Meu Controller está da seguinte forma:

```
***public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::Create([
        'name' => request('name'),
        'email' => request('email'),
        'phone' => request('phone'),
        'password' => request('password'),
        'id_enterprise' => request('id_enterprise'),
        'id_sector' => request('id_sector'),
        'active' => request('active'),
    ]);
    $user ->save();
    return response()->json(["success" => "Sucesso $user"], 200);
}***
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/hashing#hashing-passwords, a documentação tem basicamente uma linha dizendo como fazer e um exemplo. No que ficou com dúvida?

Answer (score 4):

Em Laravel usamos o `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash` e chamamos assim:

```
Hash::make($request->password)
```

No seu caso o:

```
Hash::make(request('password'))
```

> **Nota:** Diferente do que alguns pensam o Hash não tem ligação com o `APP_KEY=` do `.env`, como podem confirmar [no tweet do criador do
> Laravel](https://twitter.com/taylorotwell/status/1027290106648875008).

Atualmente o hash suporta dois drivers e você pode escolher qual usar configurando no `config/hashing.php` do seu projeto, sendo eles:

- `Bcrypt`
- `Argon2` (Argon2i requer PHP7.2.0+ e Argon2id requer PHP7.3.0+)

Comment: *Nota: Diferente do que alguns pensam o Hash não tem ligação com o APP_KEY= do .env, como podem confirmar no tweet do criador do Laravel.* -- isso acaba sendo um pesadelo de segurança. Não conheço uma forma de configurar um salto "customizado" para utilizar nas aplicações. Por este motivo eu prefiro implementar a minha própria função de hash usando duas variáveis de salto: um contexto de ambiente e um contexto do que está sendo hasheado.

Comment: @CypherPotato eu prefiro nem usar Laravel, xD. Só pra constar, até antes do PHP8 o salt era opcional em `crypt`, mas agora não é mais https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php. Note  também que em em password_hash a opção salt (em PASSWORD_BCRYPT) é **obsoleta** e a partir do PHP8 essa opção é ignorada. A intenção no caso de password_hash é gerar isso automaticamente.